# Extract the contents of ELF and write to binary file

Tags: linux, awk, dd, tail, binary-files

I have been trying to extract the contents of a firmware and putting it to a binary file, but with no success.

I see the right hex contents, but am not sure how to laid them in bits into a file.

```
objdump -s -j .text firmware.ko | tail -n +5 | awk '{print "dd if='firmware.ko' of='content.bin' bs=1 count=$["$2 $3 $4 $5 "]"}'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20898354/objdump-to-extract-contents-of-text-segment-to-a-binary-format

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
objcopy -j .text -O binary firmware.ko firmware.text
```

The file `firmware.text` should then contain what you want.

---

**UPDATE:**  The above should work if the firmware file is in the same format that your machine (running `objcopy`) uses.  If it is not the case, you'll be getting:

```
objcopy: Unable to recognise the format of the input file `firmware-arm.ko'
```

Then you'll have to specify the format yourself with `-I`.  Using `file` will tell you what format your firmware is in, e.g.:

```
$ file firmware-arm.ko
firmware-arm.ko: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), BuildID[sha1]=0xec2e703615d915dd1cad09ecc12ff7d57ef186a5, not stripped
```

And then (for this case where you have an ELF 32 little endian) you'll need:

```
objcopy -j .text -O binary -I elf32-little firmware-arm.ko firmware-arm.text
```

Comment: I could not just objcopy as

objcopy: Unable to recognise the format of the input file

Comment: If `objdump` works, I cannot see why `objcopy` should not work.  What is the format of your file?  You can specify it with `-I` if you know it, e.g. `-I elf64-x86-64`.

Comment: Using objdump -s -j firmware.ko. It states that it is > file format elf32-little
Using file formware.ko. It states that it is 
ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV)

Thank you, @nickie.

Comment: I used 
objcopy -I elf32-little -j .text -O binary firmware.ko content.bin

I think it works now.

Thank you, @nickie. You saved the day.

Comment: Assuming you're also running `objcopy` on your ARM machine, I don't think you'd need anything special.  If not, I'd suggest `-I elf32-arm` but I don't know if your `objcopy` supports that.

Comment: OK, I think I've figured this out.  I'm updating the answer...

Comment: Just to make sure my comment above does not confuse anybody: I don't know if an `elf32-arm` format is recognized by any version of `objcopy`.  If not, try `elf32-little`, this should work.